# SQL or SQLite for android database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have to do a project, Android App Application that has a database,
this is the first time to me to program for android .

so, is it better to use SQL or SQLite ?

in fact I just started with SQLite but I found a problem with Foreign keys. even I wrote it in the code,, but it doesn't work !

any help please  ?

Comment: SQL is a query language, SQLite is a database management system. One would use SQL on a variety of vendors' database servers, including SQLite3.

Comment: You should also describe the problem you are having with your foreign keys as someone may be able to assist you.

Comment: Basically, SQLite, it is small in terms of data size.

Answer (score 4):

SQL is no database. It is a query language for databases. You have to use SQLite

Answer (score 1):

The Android library provides native support to only SQLite if you need to use other databases, you'll have to either look for already-existing third-party libraries.

Here you can download DBadapter that I'm using. you need just specify your DB name and path.
Also no problem with FK. Here I've uploaded file: 
http://www.2shared.com/document/Ik6fFuth/DBAdapter.html

Answer (score 0):

here is the simple tutorial to start with android database along with source code

[click here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) !

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys constraints are not enforced by default. You need to execute the "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;" to turn them on. If you're using the default [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) You can do this in onOpen method:

```
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
  super.onOpen(db);
  if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much, I put this method in the DBAdapter class , but they are still not work